# How to calculate big-Oh time complexity in terms of n in each case?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Q2. Consider the following code fragments (a), (b) and (c) where n is the variable specifying data
size and C is a constant. **What is the big-Oh time complexity in terms of n in each case? Show all**
necessary steps.

**(a)**

`for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + C) 
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
         Sum[i] += j * Sum[i];`

**(b)**

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * C)
       for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            Sum[i] += j * Sum[i];
```

**(c)**

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
     for (int j = 0; j < n; j = j + 2)
            Sum[i] += j * Sum[i];
```

Comment: Are we being graded on this?

Comment: guess it's algorithm 101. as i remember it (vaguely) , a: O(n), b: O(n^2), c: O(n log(n))

Comment: @Shiping #2 is definitely not O(n^2) (it's also logarithmic)

Comment: @zerkms oh it's i * C, i mistook it as also i + C. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
     1.          for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + C) 
     2.               for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
     3.                  Sum[i] += j * Sum[i]; 

`

 Line 1: int i=0, takes constant time of 1 so O(1)
         i<n, takes n+1 time so O(n)
         i=i+C, takes n time so O(n)



         Total time: 1+(n+1)+n= 2n+2


 Line 2:
         int j=0, takes constant time of 1 so O(1)
         j<10, loops through 10 times and takes n time so O(n)
         i=i+C, loops through 10 times and takes n time so O(n)



         Total time: 1+(10+10)n= 1+20n

 Line 3:


         Sum[i]=Sum[i]+j*Sum[i];

        Addition and Multiplication takes constant time of 2 and plus 1 to store 
        or assign the value, and it loops through n times.


             Total time:3n

T(n)=(2n+2)+(1+20n)+3n= 25n+3 is O(n) right?
```